# Docker app won`t work but application works if not in docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, dockerfile

I have built a react and node app and it works. I am trying to build an docker image and run it it compiles but when i try to access it thru thr browser it says This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect. This is the dockerfile that i`ve written because I think this is the problem:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /client

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /client/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]




FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR ./

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: How are you starting the container?  How does the application listen on its network port?  Are you on a VM-based environment like Docker Toolbox?

Comment: Have you done 1 Dockerfile for both apps?

Comment: Yes I have 1 Dockerfile for both apps

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you can reach your server - you app may be running locally but it doesn't use the same server as the one from your dockerfile e.g. `npm start` starts a local server.

Remove everything related to the react app stage from your dockerfile and just make sure you can hit your server on port 5000 and that it servers pages - you can host an index.html with `<body>Hello world</body>` or something. When you're able to do that it's just a matter of adding the react app bundled files to the server static (public) folder

Is your node server listening on port 5000 ?
Typically with node js server you have to set a PORT and HOST env variables that are used by the server like `process.env.PORT` and `process.env.HOST`

---

### Other issues

> # start app
> CMD ["npm", "start"]

`npm start` is (usually) used to start a local server while you develop your react app

Instead of starting the app you should run a bundle command that will produce static files to be hosted - js html etc...
Typically `npm run build`

This should make a folder `./dist` or `./build` with all the static content you should put on the server (perhaps that's your /client folder for?)

Some tweaks

```sh
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine AS builder

# set working directory
WORKDIR /client

# Copy source
COPY . .

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH (you probably don't need this)
ENV PATH /client/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent (you can move this to dependencies)

# Build bundle 
RUN npm run build

# Next stage
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
WORKDIR ./

# Copy source
COPY . .

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Copy js bundle
COPY --from=builder /client/dist ./public

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

This might need a little more tweaking but that's the general idea

---

you don't need to install `react-scripts` globally it can just be a local dependency - it's used by `npm start` and `npm build` to build your app so you depend on it - it should be part of package.json dependencies

Adding `/client/node_modules/.bin` to PATH shouldn't be needed, maybe it's a leftover or a tell that something else isn't properly setup

Comment: I tried your answear it works fine till it reaches npm run build and it gives me an error that says: missing script : build What should I do next ? Thanks

Comment: That's just an example to be used as a guide. How you bundle your app depends on your own specific configuration - instead of `npm run build` run the script that bundles your app. For example **create react app** have a `build` script: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/

Comment: Your initial problem is reaching the server - it's not related to react but only to your nodejs server, so try to fix and reach the server and then add the part that bundles your app